# Prove that probability of winning stays the same

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Players $A$ and $B$ play tennis. When $A$ draws he wins the draw with probability $p_1$, when $B$ draws he wins the draw with probability $p_2$. Player $A$ draws first and the game is won by a player who reaches $n$ successful draws first. There are two ways to determine who draws next:

1. Switch after every draw (i.e. $ABABAB...$)
2. Switch at the moment the current drawer loses his draw (i.e. if $A$ has 5 successful draws and then fails, then B has 3 successful draws then fails we'll get $AAAAABBBA...$)

Prove that probability of player $A$ winning is the same no matter which rule of switching drawing players is adopted.

**My approach**:

I got that for the first scheme the probability of $A$ winning is $P(A) = \sum_{N=n}^{\infty} [p_1 \cdot \binom{N-1}{n-1} p_{1}^{n-1} q_{1}^{N-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{N-1}{k} p_{2}^k q_{2}^{N-k-1} ]$, where $N$ is all possible draws at which $A$ won and $k$ runs through amount of successful draws for $B$. I am struggling to come up with formula for $P(A)$ for the second scheme.

Comment: What is *drawing* in tennis ? Do you mean *serving* ? Is there any relation between $p_1$ and $p_2$ ? When does the game end ?  Your question seems vague

Comment: @trueblueanil (1) I can tell from context that draw means serve. (2) Both $p_1$ and $p_2$ can vary freely between $0$ and $1$. Usually, the server has an advantage, but there is no reason to assume servers have the same advantage. (3) Quoting the question: "the game is won by a player who reaches $n$ successful draws first".

Comment: @trueblueanil, sorry that my question is not clear, English is not my first language. I believe interpretation above from Mike Earnest matches what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_1, A_2, \dots \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p_1)$, and $B_1, B_2, \dots \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p_2)$, independently.

In the first version of the game, let $S_k$ denote the event that player $A$ wins the game after losing exactly $k$ of their draws; in the second version, define $T_k$ similarly. Then

$$\mathbb P(S_k) = \mathbb P\left(A_{n+k}=1, \sum_{i=1}^{n+k-1} A_i = n-1,\sum_{i=1}^{n+k-1} B_i \le n-1\right)=\mathbb P(T_k).$$

Thus the event $S$ that $A$ wins in the first version, and the event $T$ that $A$ wins in the second version, satisfy

$$\mathbb P(S) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(S_k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(T_k) = \mathbb P(T).$$

Comment: Thanks, but I think $\mathbb P(T_k)$ does not equal that because player $B$ could've had much more draws than $n+k-1$, hence upper bound for sum of $B_i$'s should be different.

Comment: No, it's the same bound. For $T_k$ to occur, we need $B$ to have at most $n-1$ wins before their first $k$ losses; in other words, we need $B$'s first $n+k-1$ draws to contain at most $n-1$ wins. Yes, it's possible that $B$ can have extra draws, but we don't need to check what they are to find out if $T_k$ occurred. @НазарПетровский